# Making sure words do not repeat when populating grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When my grid is created it is supposed to have 6 unique words in, but at the moment it generates 6 words that are sometimes duplicated.

I need someone to help me write a function to get around this problem.

Here I have the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/qBzPx/

Here is the list of words with sounds and images attached...

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">
  <li data-word="mum" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/e/7/f/1195445022768793934Gerald_G_Lady_Face_Cartoon_1.svg.med.png"></li>
  <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/9/9/5/119543969236915703Gerald_G_Cartoon_Cat_Face.svg.med.png"></li>
  <li data-word="dog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/9/4/1/1195440435939167766Gerald_G_Dog_Face_Cartoon_-_World_Label_1.svg.med.png"></li>
  <li data-word="bug" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/b/4/2/1216180545881311858laurent_scarabe.svg.med.png"></li>
  <li data-word="rat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/j/X/e/k/D/mouse-md.png"></li>
  <li data-word="dad" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/H/I/n/C/p/Z/bald-man-face-with-a-mustache-md.png"></li>
```

Lastly here is the script....

```
        var listOfWords = [];

var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");

var i;
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){

   listOfWords.push({
         "name"   : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
         "pic"    : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
         "audio"  : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
      });
  }

console.log(listOfWords);

var chosenWords = [];

  for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
    console.log('name ' + listOfWords[rand].name);
    chosenWords.push(listOfWords[rand].name);

    if (chosenWords.length < 12){
                chosenWords.push('  ');   
      }

    }

console.log(chosenWords);
var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

var guesses = {};
console.log(shuffledWords);
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    console.log(shuffledWords);
   for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        console.log(j);
        console.log(word);
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
             var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is variant:

```
var helper_array = [];
var keysOfWords= {};
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){

    keysOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = i;
    listOfWords.push({
        "name"   : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic"    : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio"  : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
    helper_array.push({
        "name"   : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic"    : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio"  : ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
}

var chosenWords = [];

for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (helper_array.length));
    console.log('name ' + helper_array[rand].name);
    chosenWords.push(helper_array[rand].name);

    helper_array.splice(rand,1);

    if (chosenWords.length < 12){
        chosenWords.push('  ');   
    }

}
```

And where we need play sound:

```
$("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[keysOfWords[rndWord]].audio);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kir Dont suppose you could tell me why my images and sounds ar'nt coming up when I press the "next" button?

Comment: So.. listOfWords[rndWord] is undefined because rndWord is a word, but keys in listOfWords are numerical. And the second - my solution brake its too )) because delete items from listOfWords. As an variant you can copy the `listOfWords` for example: `helper_array = listOfWords;` and replace all `listOfWords` by `helper_array` in `for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++) { ... }`

Comment: Do I replace "var listOfWords = [];" with "helper_array = listOfWords;" or do I add it in addition? @Kir

Comment: Problem is that in JS objects copying by link. And if we change one object, second changed too. Now I change my script

Comment: I changed script. If we need to hind values in listOfWords by word not key we need to use the `keysOfWords` array

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only six words, a quick way to do this would be to loop until the selected word list is six entries in size and keep generating random IDs until you have non-duplicated words in the list. All you have to do is keep checking the contents of the array against the random word until it's done.

I'm sure there are more elegant approaches, but it'll execute so fast your users won't notice anything.